# How do I restart nrepl

Tags: clojure, nrepl

I'm looking for a command equivalent to slimes ,restart. From the tools.nrepl source there appears to be a restart functionality present[1](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl/blob/a22aaeec88ed560a728eb7126650a59fcabf8265/src/main/clojure/clojure/tools/nrepl.clj#L52).

Any ideas on how do I make nrepl.el call that code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`nrepl-restart` is an interactive function, so <kbd>M-x nrepl-restart</kbd>.

Comment: NB. this doesn't actually call any code from `tools.nrepl`, it just does `nrepl-quit` followed by `nrepl-jack-in`. This kills the Clojure process if it was created by `nrepl-jack-in`; if it wasn't, then it attempts to jack in and fails, but the Clojure process lives on (and you can connect to it again with `M-x nrepl`).